# proportion of primes in a polynomial sequence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

It is conjectured (Bunyakovsky) that when $P(x)$ is a polynomial from $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, irreducible, with positive leading coefficient and so that the integers $P(n)$ , $n\gt0$  do not share a common factor different from $1$, then there are infinitely many primes in the sequence $P(n)$ , $n\gt0$ .

But what about the proportion (density) of those primes? It seems that it can vary a lot, even when the degree of the polynomial is not changed.

For instance, for degree $10$, let $$P(x)=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+x^6-x^7+x^8-x^9+x^{10}$$
and  $$Q(x)=-691+2073 x-287 x^2-3285 x^3+1420 x^4+2310 x^5-1190 x^6-1050 x^7+525 x^8+525 x^9+105 x^{10}$$
there are more than $60$ values of $n$ below $1000$, for which $P(n)$ is prime, whereas in the same range, $Q(n)$ is prime only when $n=129$ or $n=539$.

Can somebody find another such polynomial sequence, with an even lesser proportion of primes?

Comment: I think there is a generalized version of Szemeredi's Theorem for polynomials by Vitaly Burgelson that you would be interested in.

Comment: If you continue the calculation out far enough, the density of primes represented by any univariate polynomial should be zero. Nothing to prevent one polynomial doing much better than another one initially.

Comment: Certainly, the frequency will depend on how many roots of the polynomial modulo $2$,$3$,$5$, etc. For example, if $p(x)$ has no roots modulo $2$, that will be very different from the case where $p(0)$ or $p(1)$ is even, since we will won't even be able to try half of the values $n$. Same can happen for $p=3,5$. Etc. You can can force it so that there are no values under $1000$ just using Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: $n^6+1091$ is composite for all $n$, $1\le n\le3095$, but prime for $n=3096$. $x^{12}+488669$, similarly, for $n=616980$. You probably want to look up the Bateman-Horn conjecture.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal Bergelson*

Comment: @GerryMyerson $n^6+1091$ is first prime for $n=3906$, not 3096.

Comment: @Rosie, yes. Apologies for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chinese remainder theorem.

Pick $R(x)$ with positive coefficients so that $$\begin{align}
R(x)&\equiv x^9(x-2)\pmod 3\\
R(x)&\equiv x^7(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\pmod 5\\
R(x)&\equiv x^5(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)\pmod 7\\
R(x)&\equiv (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)(x-7)(x-8)(x-9)(x-10)\\&\equiv x^{10}-1\pmod {11}
\end{align}
$$

Then $R(n)$ will be divisible by one of $3,5,7,11$ unless $n\equiv 1\pmod 3,4\pmod 5,$ etc. This means the only $n$ we need to check is $n\equiv 1144\pmod {1155=3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot 11}$. So in particular, $R(n)$ is not prime for $n=0,1,2,3\dots,2298$.

Note, the above polynomials are not hard to compute, since, for example, $$\begin{align}
(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)&\equiv\frac{x^6-3^6}{x-3} 
\\&\equiv x^5+3x^4+3^2x^3+3^3x^2+3^4x+3^5\\
&\equiv x^5+3x^4+3x^3+6x^2+4x+5\pmod 7
\end{align}$$

On the other hand, your first $P(x)$ is the polynomial for the primitive $22$nd roots of unity, which means that if $p\mid P(n)$ then $n$ is a primitive $22$nd root of unity, modulo $p$. That can only happen if $p\equiv 1\pmod {22}$, so, in particular, $P(n)\equiv 0\pmod {2,3,5,7}$ is not possible, and the only eliminated value modulo $11$ is $10$. This gives a far larger set of prospective value of $n$.

Comment: thank you. I have to look carefully to your detailed explanation, since I am not very familiar with the congruences for polynomials. I think I understand the general idea though.

Comment: Does this mean that as long as there is no limit constrain on the degree, it is possible to find a integer polynomial that take infinitely many prime values, but with the first one being as big as one want?  and what about the case when the degree of the polynomial is limited?

Comment: As far as I know, we don't know that *any* polynomial of degree $2$ or more takes infinitely many prime values, so it's hard to answer that question.

Comment: ok. I should say "as long as there is no limit constrain on the degree, it is possible to find an integer polynomial that _conjecturally_ take infinitely many prime values, but with the first one being as big as one want...".

Comment: well, now I think that this should be true even when the degree of the polynomial is fixed, under the assumption that there is no bound to the gap between two consecutive primes. right?

Answer (score 1):

The single-polynomial case of the Bateman-Horn conjecture says that if $f$ satisfies the Buniakowsky conditions then the number of integers $n$, $1\le n<x$, such that $f(n)$ is prime is asymptotic to $C(f)n/\log n$, where $$C(f)={1\over{\rm deg}\,f}\prod_p\left(1-{1\over p}\right)^{-1}\left(1-{N_f(p)\over p}\right)$$ where the product is over primes $p$, and $N_f(p)$ is the number of solutions of $f(n)\equiv0\pmod p$.